# How to get most popular posts from facebook page using graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I wanted to fetch most popular posts from a facebook page using Graph API. I tried https://graph.facebook.com/%pageId%/posts, But with that API I am getting recent posts from page. I wanted to filter the result with most popular posts (i.e., most shared, liked and commented). Can any body help me out how to get the popular posts from the page using the graph API.

Thanks, 
Siva.

Answer (score 5):

You can't get popular posts directly from Facebook Graph API. You can fetch the posts using the Graph API ***(/{page-id}/posts)***, then count likes, shares or comments of a post by yourself ***(/{post-id}/likes, /{post-id}/comments, /{post-id}/sharedposts)*** and then sort all the posts.

References:

1.https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/object/comments
2.https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/object/likes
3.https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/object/sharedposts

Comment: I second this, there is no direct solution. So you can only solve it in a 'dirty' way with a lot of manual implementation.

Comment: Facebook documentation are almost impossible to understand, i have the same problem and i already go through that page links you have given, but still i have no idea that how to do it. can you please show some code here.